# How to get a nice dispay after fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am experimenting with *fetch* in some web page, in order to use it in a project. And I have an issue I need to solve.

The code is below, I use a *fetch* to access my site (https://mynicewebsite.example.com), possibly setting some options (headers ....)... By using *document.getElementById('bdyID').innerHTML = await response.text();* I display the contents of the site (https://mynicewebsite.example.com) in the browser. But this way of doing shows the whole text as a long continuous character string. How can I get a nice HTML display showing the site as it usually appears in a browser when someone directly goes to visit it.

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id='bdyID'>
<script>
   const makeFetchCall = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://mynicewebsite.example.com', {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer blahfblahdblahzblah',
            //..... // possibly some other things
         }
      });

      document.getElementById('bdyID').innerHTML = await response.text();
   }

   makeFetchCall();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the display with the code above:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the display when looking directly at https://mynicewebsite.example.com in the browser:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*a nice HTML display*". Doesn't your server return the same html? Why would it look different? Are you missing the CSS or what?

Comment: A `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` *request* header makes no sense for a GET request.

Comment: It means that what I see  when looking at the page with the code in the post and what I see when looking at https://mynicewebsite.example.com directly is not the same. But I would like it to look the same. About the question "Why would it look different?"; I suppose if I knew the answer I may not have written this post.

Comment: And *how* are they looking different? How are they even looking at all? Please provide an actual example that contains the result value of `response.text()`

Comment: I just edited the post and added two screenshots. You can take a look.

Comment: Uh, that doesn't look like HTML at all? Why are you talking about html formatting, why are you using `innerHTML`?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking you may be right. But my main point is not to worry if it is or not HTML. The issue (for me) is that I don't get the same result by looking directly or after passing through fetch. Anyway your comment about "..look like HTML..", may still be useful. I will try with some other page and see how it goes.

Comment: It appears your comment was useful, it works better with some other (HTML) pages.

Comment: Yes. It won't work with an image file, which is rendered by the browser differently when opened standalone, and it doesn't work with this JSON file either which is displayed as the fancy tree when opened standalone. Your choices appear to be a) use an iframe b) use a JSON tree view library

Comment: OK. For my real need I must handle an HTML file. JSON was just a bad example used in my post. But I thought there was some better way than using "document.getElementById('bdyID').innerHTML = await response.text();". Well I learned something.

Comment: As for HTML: it could work, but probably badly for complex html pages. You cannot assign a whole document source as the `innerHTML`  of an element. The doctype declaration hopefully will be ignored, the `<head>`  tag *might* be ignored, css includes will be weird, scripts probably won't work at all, not to mention possible security problems.

Comment: Well, after going through fetch; what is the best way to have the page simply load into the browser? At this point as you can see I am no expert in using fetch; I am just learning by reading an trying.

Comment: To "simply load a page", do not go through `fetch`. Use an iframe or redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211850/discussion-between-michel-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by the content-type header that you can call .json on the response object.

```
const data = await response.json()
const formattedResponse = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
document.getElementById('bdyID').innerHTML = formattedResponse;
```

JSON.stringify take three params. the third param is space https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Be aware that you can see your response in the devtools well formatted anyway. 
Example with json and pre tag: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-platform-f6gj6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header in the OPs code is a request header, not a response header.

Comment: thats's why I said "I suppose". **Usually** you have one file type for exchanging info between server and client.  if the response is text you can use the <pre> tag

Comment: I just tried the code in you answer, but it does not make any difference and I get the same display as before.

Comment: @Michel I updated the answer with a codesandbox example. you can format the json and then put it in a pre tag.